# Ephemeral TFS Build Agent Setup

Tags: .net, tfs, vagrant, .net-core

I'm using TFS 2017 to build enterprise .net and .net core applications on virtual build agents.

I create the virtual build agents using Vagrant from TFS itself but need to automate the installation of the TFS Build Agent and registration to the central server.

The end result will be Ephemeral TFS Build Agents that I can rebuild at will, even on the fly if it's quick enough.

Has anyone managed to automate the Build Agent install and registration and if so how?

Comment: It's all command-line based. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Well interestingly the [2015 official docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v1-windows) show numerous command line parameters but the [TFS 2017 docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) don't.  It does indicate the help option will show unattended configuration so I'll check that next. Thanks!

Comment: So further wranglings on this confirm the command line options are there in the 2017 version if not documented online - will post a working example when I succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to automate it in the end by combining **downloading and unzipping** of the 2017 vsts agent, with **registering the agent**:

```
$VSTSAgentFileName="vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.105.7.zip"
$VSTSAgentDownloadUrl="http://yourvstsagentdownloadserver/" + $VSTSAgentFileName
$TempFolder="c:/Temp/"
$VSTSAgentDownloadPath=$TempFolder + $VSTSAgentFileName
$VSTSAgentFolder="c:/vsts_agent"
$TFSServerUrl="http://yourtfsserver:8080/tfs"

function Download-VSTSAgent{
    Write-Host("Downloading: " + $VSTSAgentDownloadUrl)
    Write-Host("To: " + $VSTSAgentDownloadPath)
    $WebClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $WebClient.DownloadFile($VSTSAgentDownloadUrl, $VSTSAgentDownloadPath)
}

function Unzip-VSTSAgent{
    Write-Host("Unzipping: " + $VSTSAgentDownloadPath)
    Write-Host("To: " + $VSTSAgentFolder)
    Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
    [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory($VSTSAgentDownloadPath, $VSTSAgentFolder)
}

function Register-VSTSAgent{
    cd $VSTSAgentFolder
    & .\config.cmd --unattended --auth Negotiate --username yourdomain\yourusername --password yourpw --url $TFSServerUrl --pool yourpool
}

Download-VSTSAgent
Unzip-VSTSAgent
Register-VSTSAgent
```

**Note:** I used authentication of Negotiate as PAT wasn't working for me so you would need to securely pass in credentials in the `Register-VSTSAgent` function - or even better use PAT auth.

Finally, if you want to know the commands that the `.\config.cmd` has use `.\config.cmd --help` - as noted above the documentation for 2017 doesn't detail these.